# Error getting Connection Cloud data using Xpages and IBM SBT

Tags: java, oauth, xpages, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I'm trying to connect to Connections Cloud to get data and display it in xpages using IBM SBT, but I'm having some troubles.
I have installed the IBM SBT on Domino Server and deployed it to Domino Designer after reading the installation guide.

I have also a smartcloud account, where I have registered an internal app for OAuth testing.

[Internal app credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iln6r.png)

I created a new nsf application, copied the managed-beans from the sample XPagesSBT.nsf database and replace the OAuth1 credentials. The faces-config.xml looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config>
    <!--
        Token store Memory implementation
    -->
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>CredStore</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.ibm.sbt.security.credential.store.MemoryStore
        </managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <!--
        SmartCloud 
   -->
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>connections</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>
            com.ibm.sbt.services.endpoints.SmartCloudOAuthEndpoint
        </managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
        <!-- Endpoint URL -->
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>url</property-name>
            <value>https://apps.na.collabserv.com
            </value>
        </managed-property>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>serviceName</property-name>
            <value>SmartCloud</value>
        </managed-property>
        <!-- OAuth parameters -->
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>credentialStore</property-name>
            <value>CredStore
            </value>
        </managed-property>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>requestTokenURL</property-name>
            <value>https://apps.na.collabserv.com/manage/oauth/getRequestToken
            </value>
        </managed-property>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>authorizationURL</property-name>
            <value>https://apps.na.collabserv.com/manage/oauth/authorizeToken
            </value>
        </managed-property>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>accessTokenURL</property-name>
            <value>https://apps.na.collabserv.com/manage/oauth/getAccessToken
            </value>
        </managed-property>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>appId</property-name>
            <value>app_20051314_...</value>
        </managed-property>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>consumerKey</property-name>
            <value>3f1b3f22658601...
            </value>
        </managed-property>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>consumerSecret</property-name>
            <value>bcb4ca1d1ede5...
            </value>
        </managed-property>
    </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

I selected the [Xpage Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3uwT.png) to use and finally I created an Xpage based on this Snippet taken from Greenhouse:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    Here is the list of public Communities:
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:text escape="false" id="computedField1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var svc = new com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.communities.CommunityService()
var c = svc.getPublicCommunities()
if(c.size()>0) {
var result = ""
for(var i=0; i<c.size(); i++) {
result += "<b>Name:</b>"+c[i].getTitle()+"<br/>\n"
}
return result;
} else {
return "No Result";
}}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:text>
</xp:view>
```

When I open the Xpage, it redirects me to the Authentication page for Connection Cloud, then redirects to the Grant Access page and finally redirects to my Xpage with this error:

Error while calling java constructor 'com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.communities.CommunityService()' (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException).

The server release is 9.0.1FP4 on Windows/Longhom/64 6.1 and runs under https. I don't know what I'm missing. Maybe something at server level?. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it

I had installed the latest release of the SBT SDK from github (1.1.11.20151208-1200). I uninstalled it and instead install the openntf release (1.0.3.20140723-1200). Now it works fine.

Comment: I'd recommend raising an issue on GitHub, so they can identify and fix the cause.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'll heed your recommendation